# Referencing a JSON object created in Java through javascript in the one JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, json, highcharts

How can I create a JSON object in java and then reference that object through javascript in the same jsp page?

What I am doing is - 
Accessing a postgresql database -
Running an sql query and returning a result set -
Converting the result set to a JSON object

This all works fine because when I println out the JSON object at this stage it works.

Then I went to use that JSON object to feed into a Highchart. I am trying to use $.getJson but it keeps saying my JSON object is not defined! I know getjson expects a url, but any other way I have tried to access the JSON object has not worked either. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
//Do imports

//connect to database

//sql query

<%
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while( rs.next() ){
int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      //convert to JSON

      json.put(obj);
    }
   //test JSON
   System.out.println(json); 
 %>

<script>
$(function () {
    $.getJSON(json, function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    //make up chart

    //try load json into chart
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: data
    }]
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah Java code in JSPs - have we gone back in time?

Comment: Well considering that I am obviously new to JSP, can you point out what I am doing wrong please? I just want to learn JamesB!

Comment: The highcharts should be inistialised in the $.getJSON callabck, becase in this scenario it is asychrnosied, and data is get later than chart created.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a servlet which handles your Java stuff and get rid of your Java code in your JSPs. Do it now, because eventually your single JSP has grown into a full product and then it's too late to change anything because that would cost money.

The problem is, that your Java code can not be seen by your JavaScript code. The JavaScript code can't access the json variable.

Create a servlet which handles your querying and so on and returns a JSON string which then can be read by your JSP.

Comment: ok thanks s3b! I'm just going to look up a tutorial on how to do that now. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The Json variable that you are using is in a java scope and not javascript scope; in order to use the content created you should output the following

System.out.println(" var json ='" + json + "'; ");

That way the object will be an javascript object available for the whole page and you can use it in your script.